# SpringBootTest weird behavior when getting resource classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, testing

So i setup an integration test for Spring Boot like this:

```java
@Tag(TestType.INTEGRATION_TEST)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, classes = MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(provider = DatabaseProvider.ZONKY)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class IntegrationTest {}
```

So this test will spin up all of my components, one of which in particular, must retrieve a yml file from my classpath. The value of "application.hub-spot.data" is "classpath:/path/to/hubspot/config.yml".

BUT, currently that component, during test ONLY, cannot find the resource:

```java
      @Value("${application.hub-spot.data}")
    private String path;
public void example(){
    new ClassPathResource(path).getInputStream(); // this will throw an error
}
```

HOWEVER if i change it like this then the resource can be found easily

```java
    @Value("${application.hub-spot.data}")
    private Resource rsrc;
    public void example(){
    rsrc.getInputStream(); // this work
}
```

One more fact is that if i remove the "classpath:" prefix from the value, then both my current code and the ad-hoc fix one will work perfectly.

I see no documentation regarding this behaviour, so if anyone has come across this, please let me know!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is my every test class annotation

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ApplicationTests {}
```

---

```
ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/your/xml") and make sure that your compile script is copying the xml file to where in your CLASSPATH.
```

---

Some of the "getResourceAsStream()" options in this answer didn't work for me, but this one did:

```
SomeClassWithinYourSourceDir.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourResource");
```